# Sending serialized file via other apps

Tags: android

Hello I made serialized object file and I want to send it via , messenger, gmail, sms, etc. I tried to send it in this way, this is code from saving to sending. I got that no one app is connected with this.

```
File file=new File(getFilesDir() + "ShoppingList.ur");
                try{
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =new FileOutputStream(file);
                    ObjectOutputStream data=new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                    data.writeObject(toShare);
                    data.close();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                }catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                uriToSend=Uri.fromFile(file);
                Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                shareIntent.addCategory("*/*");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uriToSend);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,getString(R.string.sendTo)));
                file.delete();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hello I made serialized object file and I want to send it via , messenger, gmail, sms, etc

[Do not assume that this file will be usable anywhere](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/191269/130375).

> I got that no one app is connected with this

There are approximately zero apps that have an `<activity>` with an `<intent-filter>` with a `<category>` of `*/*`.

In addition:

- `ACTION_SENDTO` requires a `Uri` (`mailto:` or `smsto:` schemes, usually)
- You have not specified a MIME type for this file (e.g., `application/octet-stream`, since there is no official MIME type for it)
- Do not use string concatenation to assemble file paths — replace `new File(getFilesDir() + "ShoppingList.ur")` with `new File(getFilesDir(), "ShoppingList.ur")`
- You are trying to use the file even if you have an exception that did not create it
- You are deleting the file before the other app will have a chance to do anything with it
- Other apps do not have any access to your app's `getFilesDir()`, and so they will not be able to work with this file
- Using a `Uri` with a `file` scheme (`Uri.fromFile()`) is banned on Android 7.0+ for apps with a `targetSdkVersion` of 24 or higher